# Interpreting Parts of a File as Nodes and Edges

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, nodes

Your program should output a file callgraph.txt with two parts using the following structure. The two parts are separated by an empty line.

First part: the nodes

Each node is presented in one line as follows: number, phone number, name, city, total time spent; where number is a sequential number starting from 1 that identifies the node. Total time spent is the total number of seconds in calls initiated by the phone number.

Second part: the edges

Each edge is presented in one line as follows: number of origin, number of destination, weight; where number origin and destination are numbers identifying the nodes in the first part of the file.

An example of the callgraph.txt file could look like this. Note that the nodes are sorted by phone number.

```
2, 7801234567, Ameneh Gholipour Shahraki, Hinton, 198473
7, 7801236789, Stuart Johnson, Saint Albert, 64399
4, 7803214567, Md Toukir Imam, Sherwood Park, 179532
8, 7804321098, Hamman Samuel, Stony Plain, 57909
1, 7804922860, Osmar Zaiane, Edmonton, 250068
5, 7807890123, Elham Ahmadi, Devon, 129370
9, 7808765432, Amir Hossein Faghih Dinevari, Beaumont, 62552
6, 7808907654, Weifeng Chen, Spruce Grove, 121726
3, 7809876543, Farrukh Ahmed, Edson, 190211

2, 7, 40425
2, 4, 21618
2, 8, 34186
2, 1, 34291
2, 5, 24286
2, 9, 67786
2, 6, 21983
2, 3, 35614
7, 4, 32851
7, 8, 27293
7, 1, 45367
```

Now for my question: I am trying out to figure out how to complete the second part and I am just stuck. My question is that every unique number is a node, to which I assign a number ranging from 1 to how many unique numbers there are. What I want is when say a number calls another it will print out the two nodes and then also say for how long they talked between themselves and do that for every number. Any advice is appreciated.

This is the code I have so far, which answers the first part.

```
customers=open('customers.txt','r')
calls=open('calls.txt.','r')
nodes= {}
name={}
city={}
total_spent_time={}
with open("customers.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        number = line.split(";")[0]
        if number not in nodes:
            nodes[number] = len(nodes) + 1
        rows=line.split(";")
        name[rows[0]]=rows[1]
        city[rows[0]]=rows[2].strip("\n")
with open("calls.txt") as fp2:    
    for lines in fp2:
        rows2=lines.split(";")
        if rows2[1] not in total_spent_time:
            total_spent_time[rows2[1]]=int(rows2[3])
        elif rows2[1]  in total_spent_time:
            total_spent_time[rows2[1]]+=int(rows2[3])
    print(total_spent_time)
```

Link to  calls.txt file : http://pastebin.com/RSMnXDtq

Link to customers.txt file: http://pastebin.com/xMx15nCS

Comment: Both links to txt files are the same.

Comment: Fixed. I linked it on pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is complicated enough that it needs a plan before coding.  First, the mapping of phone numbers to sequence numbers is just a peripheral nuisance.  It can be done either on input or output.  Let forget about sequence numbers while developing a solution to the summation problem.

I assume the lines of calls.txt consist of "src dst secs".  The problem is to calculate subtotals for each (src, dst) pair and then calculate totals for each src.  A standard database report method would be to sort calls by src and dst and then calculate and print subtotals for each src, dst pair, with lines for a src followed by the total for src.  The problem originator threw a curveball by asking for all the totals to be printed before the subtotals they are based on.  Hence you first calculated totals without the subtotals.

The sort and scan method could be used here by saving the subtotals for later printing.  It would not be a bad idea for you to try this.  But we can skip sorting by using a dict mapping each src to a dict mapping each dst to a subtotal of secs for calls from that src.

```
subs = {}
with open(calls.txt) as f:
    for line in f:
        src, dst, sec = line.split()
        sub = subs.get(src, {})
        sub.get(dst, 0) += 1
```

Using .get(key, default_value) is much easier than conditional statements like those you used.  Or subs could be preloaded with (number, {}) pairs.  When subs is filled in, it will look something like the following (the phone numbers are what you sequenced as 2, 7, and 4):

```
{7801234567: {7801236789: 40425,
              7803214567: 21618,
              ...
             },
 7801236789: (7803214567: 32851,
              ...},
 ...
}
```

EDIT: revise and extend the following..

With this, it is easy to calculate the totals for each src.  The following, untested as is the above, should work.

```
totals = {key: sum(dstdict.values()) for key, dstdict in subs.items()}
```

Create another dict mapping phone numbers to sequence numbers.  The following works if everyone makes a call and is a key in subs.

```
seqs = {phone: i for i, phone in subs}
```

Otherwise augment or create this while reading the phone number file.

Comment: See, one of problems is exactly what you said was easy, calculating the total and also assigning a node number to each phone number.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind combining all of that so I could see a clearer picture?

Comment: sub.get(dst, 0) += 1 is also not syntactically correct

Answer (score 0):

Use an iterator `it` to read from file in two steps.
As soon as you get an empty line, stop the first loop.
An iter here will point to the next line allowing you to continue iterating after the `break` instruction.

Also, I added usage of namedtuple type which seems to fit organically into your task.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Call = namedtuple('Call', ['number', 'phone_number', 'name', 'city', 'total_time_spent'])

with open('out.txt', 'r') as f:
    it = iter(f)
    calls = []
    for line in it:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            break
        call = Call(*line.split(', '))
        calls.append(call)


    for line in it:
        # code is similar
```

I guess, you can write the second part yourself )

Comment: What exactly does this do?

Comment: Added a comment. Plz let me know if this is not clear enough yet

Comment: How will that work with the nodes that I want? Because my question is that every unique  number is a node, to which I assign a number ranging from 1 to how many unique numbers there are. What I want is when say a number calls another it will print out the two nodes and then also say for how long they talked between themselves and do that for every number.

Comment: Sorry, you just didn't specify any question in the original post so I thought the question is how to read the data separated by empty line. I suggest you to update the post

Comment: No problem, I updated it now. Do you think you can still help me with this?